# What is the equivalence of BETWITHIN degrees of freedom in mixed-effect models R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, sas, degrees-of-freedom

As in the title. Let's assume I cannot use the Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite method in mixed-effect models. I was told to use the BETWITHIN method. Now I switched to R. I can use any package I want. Which option in nlme, lme4, glmmTMB or glmmPQL corresponds to that?  I know this question may seem to much bound to R, but I believe it's more statistical than technical, so I post it here.

Comment: "Let's assume I cannot use the Kenward-Roger or Satterthwaite method" .... on what? What's the context here, please?

Comment: I'm sorry for not putting that clearly. I mean mixed-effect models (GLIMMIX in SAS, glmmTMB or lme4 in R).